# How to use LetsEncrpyt with Nginx and Gunicorn?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I deployed Django to DigitalOcean with the Gunicorn and the Nginx successfully. I want to switch to HTTPS then I have installed LetsEncrpyt with [the Digitalocean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

**This my Nginx confguration file:** (/etc/nginx/sites-available/[MY_DOMAIN] 
)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name [MY_DROPLETS_IP_ADDRESS];

    return 301 $scheme://[MY_DOMAIN].com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name www.[MY_DOMAIN].com;
  return 301 $scheme://[MY_DOMAIN].com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name [MY_DOMAIN].com;

    access_log off;

    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[MY_DOMAIN].com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[MY_DOMAIN].com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/data/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

**This is the `sudo ufw status verbose` output:**

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**This is the `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` output:**

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-10-21 16:46:22 UTC; 19min ago
```

The [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=efsanefikirler.com) says: `Assessment failed: No secure protocols supported`

**I'm running the Gunicorn like this:**

```
gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

**This is the Nginx error log:**

```
2017/10/21 17:27:56 [error] 2369#2369: *46 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 86.169.162.151, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

**This is what is see when I try to enter site:**

[image: This is what is see when I try to enter site.]

Where is my problem?

Comment: gunicorn has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you. I added that info too because I don't know is it related to this problem.

Comment: What does your nginx error log show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added it to question, thank you.

Comment: You also need a different certificate for www redirect as it is a different domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening to port 443 in all instances and then try to redirect to port 443. Remove the listen directive for port 443 on the first server.

On the third server, you specify SSL certs but you also say you are listening on port 80. I'm not sure that can work that way.

What you want is one server to listen on port 80 and in all instances redirect to https. Then have just one https server listening on 443.

One way to do this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com;
    root /var/empty;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  myserver.com www.myserver.com;
    root /home/myserver;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    if ($host = www.$server_name) {
      rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but I didn't use `http2`, what is this?

Comment: HTTP/2 is the latest and greatest  version of HTTP over version 1.1. You don't need to use HTTP/2 but I do and forgot to change that for you. I think you just remove that, the http2 part, and you'll be fine.